# pass data with formData from angular to php (mysql)

Tags: php, arrays, angular, service, request

I am using `formData` to append image information and extract it into my API using php.

**I  append my data like this:**

```
    insertService(nom: string, fileToUpload: File): Promise<any> {
        const url = 'http://localhost/Admin/src/api/api.php?action=insertService';
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', fileToUpload);

        const param = {nom: nom, image: formData};
        console.log(param);
        const request = this.http.post(url, param);
        return request.toPromise();
}
```

So as you can see I append my data to 'image'.

**And here I am trying to extract it**

```
 $nom = $_POST['nom'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];

        echo ('nom ' .$nom);
        echo ('image :' .$image);
        echo($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $filetmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $filepath = "../assets/img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);

        $query = 'INSERT into etservice(nom_service,image_ser) values("' . $nom . '","' . $filepath . '")';
        $result = $db->query($query);
        if ($result === TRUE) {
            $res = "Inserted'$nom' and image '$image' ";
            echo json_encode($res);
        } else {
            echo json_encode("Error" . $query . "<br>" . $db->error);
        }
```

It shows me this error

> Notice:  image : Array to string conversion

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Why are you setting `image` to be `formData`? It sounds like you want something like `image: formData['image']`.

Comment: it tell me undefined and when i do `image : formData.get('image'); it keep me the same error`

Comment: nobody can help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

$nom = $_POST['nom'];

to

$nom = $_REQUEST['nom'];

and everything will work fine